# How to get data from a sign Computer Craft

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

is there a way of getting what is written on a sign from a turtle, the furthest I've gotten is getting that it's a sign... yeah.

If anyone knows how to do it, please do tell.

To make it more clear, I have a sign with "Hello" written on it, I want the turtle to read the sign and output the "Hello" to the console.

Comment: Since signs store their text in blockentities, and a turtles can not interact with those, It is probably not possible. A google search also leaded me to (old and outdated) addons to read signs. http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/665-turtle-read-signs/